# How to find out whether iOS app was signed with a development or a distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, code-signing-certificate

I'd like to know whether an iOS app can find out whether it was signed with a development or a distribution certificate.

I found that an iOS app can fetch some meta-information about itself by accessing the info dictionary of the bundle. For example, the version can be retrieved by reading the CFBundleVersion key from the dictionary. Does there exist something similar for getting signing certificate information?

The reason why I ask, is because of APNS. When my app registers an APNS device token to my cloud server, the cloud server needs to know whether push messages for that token need to be created by calling Apple's production APNS server ("api.push.apple.com") or development APNS server "api.development.push.apple.com".

Comment: The APNS settings is stored in the entitlements, not the signing certificate. Have you had a look at the source to the `codesign` tool?

Comment: I didn't look in the source of the codesign tool. Your remark about entitlements is interesting. I see that my project contains a file with extension ".entitlements". The file specifies that the key "APS Environment" has the value "development". So accessing that information from the app would also be a solution to my problem. I don't know (yet) how to get that information programmatically from my Swift code, but thanks for this hint!

Comment: The value is set to either `development` or `production` during the code signing build phase. This depends on the code signing certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: Here is a step-by-step instruction for reading app entitlements at runtime: https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/01/10/reading-your-own-entitlements

Answer (score 0):

The information about the APNS server is in the entitlements in the code signing section of your binary. The basic steps are:

1. Get the load address of your binary from `dladdr`.
2. Loop through all Mach-O load commands for `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE`
3. Parse the code signature command the same way as the `codesign` tool. It is open sourced on opensource.apple.com.
4. Parse the entitlements plist-data.
5. Extract the aps-environment value.

This is basically the same as running the command `codesign -d --entitlements :-` on your binary.